# Detect if a file was created with todays date and then remove older files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a script which deletes files older than +2 days in a specific Directory.
I would like to check if there is a file with todays date created before removing the older files.
This is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

find /var/backups/server1 -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
find /var/backups/server2 -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
find /var/backups/server3 -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
find /var/backups/server4 -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
find /var/backups/server5 -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
```

So Basically:
1.Check Directory with file with todays date.
2.If affirmative find /var/backups/serverX -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
3.If not "execute scriptX" (which maybe a mail notification)

thanks!

Comment: So, if there is a file with today's date, you want to delete older files. & if there is no file, what should happen? delete files older than day-before-yesterday? or do nothing?

Comment: In other words, do you want to keep latest one and delete all older?

Comment: So Basically: 1.Check Directory with file with todays date. 2.If affirmative find /var/backups/serverX -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \; 3.If not "execute scriptX" (which maybe a mail notification)

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
find /var/backups/ -maxdepth 1 -type d  -print0 | while read -rd '' dirname 
do
arry=( $(find "${dirname}" -type f -atime 0) )
#Checks if there is a file that is updated today.
[ "${#arry[@]}" -ge 1 ] && find "${dirname}" -type f -mtime +2 -exec rm {} \;
done
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The Problem is that Directory name is not always server, there are over 50 serversdifferent names . So I guess the "for i in {1..4} do arry=( $(find /var/backups/server"${i}" would not work in my case

Comment: @JoseluisVanta : Please see the update and use  `find -print0 - read -d ''` combination to parse non-standard names

Comment: "find ... -atime 0" is true for any file accessed in the last 24 hours. Better "-mtime 0" (files modified in last 24 hours) or, if your "find" version supports it "find . -type f -newerBt yesterday"

Comment: @GiovanniLenti As you rightly said, `-newerBt` is not widely implemented and the test  might fail when the birth-time is unknown.

Comment: @sjsam : You still need to change `-atime` to `-mtime`. ?